# drawing objects in queue in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, drawing

I'm trying to make a game on pygame, it will be 2-d survival. i want to draw all my objects one by one. for example, if my 'y' is lower than the object's, then the object is drawn first and I'm on top of it. here's my main code:

```
import pygame
import random
from models.maps import *
from models.Basic import *
from models.Me import *
from models.Enemies import add_enemy,create_enemy
from models.Watch import Watch
from models.Objects import *
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('Dino Islands')
watch=Watch()

#ANIMATION WATER
water_choice=random.randint(-2,0)
water_animation_side='down'
water_animation_count=0
water_animation_time=pygame.USEREVENT+2
pygame.time.set_timer(water_animation_time,500)
def water_animation(its_x,its_y,id):
    global water_animation_side,water_animation_count
    sprite_image = sprites.get(id)['image']
    if water_animation_side=='up':
        water_animation_count-=0.002
    else:
        water_animation_count+=0.002
    if water_animation_count<-9:
        water_animation_side='down'
    elif water_animation_count>9:
        water_animation_side='up'
    if sprite_image:
        screen.blit(sprite_image[water_choice+1], ((its_x - camera_x)* TILE_SIZE, (its_y - camera_y) * TILE_SIZE-TILE_SIZE/2+water_animation_count+random.randint(-10,10)/10))
        screen.blit(sprite_image[water_choice], ((its_x - camera_x)* TILE_SIZE, (its_y - camera_y) * TILE_SIZE+water_animation_count+water_animation_count+random.randint(-10,10)/10))

#DRAWING CURRENT MAP
def draw_map(my_map):
    for y in range(int(camera_y), int(camera_y) + 9):
        for x in range(int(camera_x), int(camera_x) + 14):
            if -1 <= y < SIZE_H and 0 <= x < SIZE_W:
                sprite_id = my_map[y][x]
                if sprite_id!=3:
                    sprite_image = sprites.get(sprite_id)['image']
                    if sprite_image:
                        screen.blit(sprite_image, ((x - camera_x)* TILE_SIZE, (y - camera_y) * TILE_SIZE))
                elif sprite_id==3:
                    water_animation(x,y,sprite_id)


running = True
while running:
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    m_click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    m_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill((52, 152, 219))

    #Main Game
    if window=='game':
        camera_x =max(2,min((camera_x-(camera_x-player.x)/30)-0.2,SIZE_W-2))
        camera_y =max(2,min((camera_y-(camera_y-player.y)/30)-0.1,SIZE_H-2))

        draw_map(lvl_1)
        #ALL THE OBJECTS IN THE LIST (INCLUDE ME)
        for object in objects:
            object.draw(screen,camera_x,camera_y)
            if player.image_cross_rect.colliderect(object.rect) and object.type=='tree':
                object.hp-=player.skills['attack']
            if object.type=='enemy':
                object.move(player.x,player.y,object.speed)
                if abs(object.x-player.x)<3 and abs(object.y-player.y)<3:
                    object.sees_player=True
                else:
                    object.sees_player=False
                if object.hp<=0:
                    objects.remove(object)
                if player.rect.colliderect(object.rect):
                    player.hp-=object.attack
            if object.type=='tree':
                pass
            drawing_y+=1
            if drawing_y>HEIGHT:
                drawing_y=0

        player.control()
        watch.show_time(screen)
        inventory.draw(screen,(WIDTH-inventory.ile*inventory.scale)/2,HEIGHT-inventory.image.get_height()-10)
        player.draw_ui(screen)
        # if player.hp<=0:
        #     window='game_over'
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==player.animation_count:
            if player.animation_image==0:
                player.animation_image=1
            else:
                player.animation_image=0
            if player.position=='idle':
                if player.direction=='right':
                    player.image=animation_player[player.animation_image]
                if player.direction=='left':
                    player.image=animation_player[player.animation_image+2]
                if player.direction=='up':
                    player.image=animation_player[player.animation_image+4]
                if player.direction=='down':
                    player.image=animation_player[player.animation_image+6]
            elif player.position=='walk':
                if player.direction=='right':
                    player.image=animation_player[player.animation_image+8]
                if player.direction=='left':
                    player.image=animation_player[player.animation_image+10]
                if player.direction=='up':
                    player.image=animation_player[player.animation_image+12]
                if player.direction=='down':
                    player.image=animation_player[player.animation_image+14]

        if event.type==water_animation_time:
            water_choice=random.randint(-2,0)
        if event.type==add_enemy:
            create_enemy()
        if event.type==add_tree:
            create_trees()
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button==0:
                print(1)
            if event.button==5:
                if player.item_in_hand<inventory.ile-1:
                    player.item_in_hand+=1
                else:
                    player.item_in_hand=0
            if event.button==4:
                if player.item_in_hand>0:
                    player.item_in_hand-=1
                else:
                    player.item_in_hand=inventory.ile-1
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```

But i even don't know how to make it. please help

I tried creating a variable "drawing_y" and checking if the drawy of the object is equal to "drawing_y". but it was wrong, the objects just were not drawn

Comment: Please visit the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I don't understand your question, but I think you want to draw a picture
You can use this function to draw pictures

```
import pygame as App
Screen = App.display.set_mode(Screen_Scale)
img = App.image.load("file location")

def Draw(Image,Position):
    Screen.blit(Image,Position)
```

Draw(img,(100,200))
Can you explain to me more

Comment: If you don't understand the question there is no need to put an answer. The question is not explaining what is needed to draw. In the answer, it seems like you're loading an image from disk to the screen and this is too generic.